What is the right way of printing non formatted string not ending in new line?
printf("foo: "); 

vs
fputs("foo: ", stdout);

As mentioned in the title, the string is not formatted and does not end in a new line (so no puts). I am not sure about overheads and optimizations, so what is the rule of thumb is this case?
EDIT: Is it normal practice to use printf with non-formatted strings?

If you're worried about optimization for this simple thing, then there's no need. The compiler, with optimizations enabled, might even recognize the printf call and emit the fputs call for you. And if not, the difference will be negligible and not even measurable.

@Someprogrammerdude I am starting out and don't know about these optimizations. So was looking for best practices. Then I'll just stick to printf then and let the compiler do the rest then. Thanks.

Rule of thumb: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

It is funny as printf and fprintf(stdout,  are treated by the optimizer diferently

@moooeeeep It was a question more about of what to use for formatted and non formatted and not about optimization, but thanks, got to know about premature optimizations too.


What is the right way

Both ways are "right", both will work the same and fine.
Consider rules of optimization. Don't optimize, if you don't have to. printf("foo: "); is completely fine, readable, understandable, everyone knows what it means. Keep it. printf("foo :"); is great.
If you really want to optimize, and you really care about speed, you could call fwrite with statically calculated values:
fwrite("foo: ", 1, sizeof("foo: ") - 1, stdout);

But I doubt that optimization is worth anything. If you would really care about speed, you would call OS specific functions anyway, like on Linux we have write or splice or tee or vmsplice or copy_file_range or sendfile.

if it is normal practice to use printf for non-formatted strings

Let's take some big project and check. Analyzing gcc source code, there are that many lines matching fputs with a literal string:
$ rg -g '*.[ch]' 'fputs\s*\(\s*"[^"]*"' gcc/ | wc -l
263
$ rg -g '*.[ch]' 'fputs\s*\(\s*"[^"]*"' gcc/ | head
gcc/defaults.h:    fputs (":\n", (FILE));                       \
gcc/defaults.h:    fputs (":\n", (FILE));                       \
gcc/defaults.h:      fputs (", ", STREAM);                              \
gcc/defaults.h:      fputs (", .-", STREAM);                            \
gcc/config/csky/csky.h:      fputs ("\t.comm\t", STREAM);                               \
gcc/config/csky/csky.h:  fputs ("\t.bss\t", (STREAM));                                  \
gcc/config/xtensa/xtensa.h:    fputs ("@pcrel", FILE);                                          \
gcc/config/c6x/c6x.h:       fputs ("\t.long ", FILE);                   \
gcc/config/visium/visium.h:  do { assemble_name (STREAM, NAME); fputs (":\n", STREAM); } while (0)
gcc/config/visium/visium.h:( fputs ("\n\t.comm  ", (STREAM)),     

And that many lines matching printf with literal string and no arguments:
$ rg -g '*.[ch]' 'printf\s*\(\s*"[^"]*"\);' gcc/ | wc -l
1792

There are that many lines with printf that have no newlines in formatting string:
$ rg -g '*.[ch]' 'printf\s*\(\s*"[^"]*"\);' gcc/ | grep -v '"[^"]*\\n[^"]*"' | wc -l
470
$ rg -g '*.[ch]' 'printf\s*\(\s*"[^"]*"\);' | grep -v '"[^"]*\\n[^"]*"' | head
zlib/contrib/minizip/miniunz.c:          printf(" ");
libdecnumber/decNumber.c:    if (decNumberIsInfinite(dn)) printf("Infinity");
libdecnumber/decNumber.c:      if (dn->bits&DECSNAN) printf("sNaN");  /* signalling NaN */
libdecnumber/decNumber.c:       else printf("NaN");
libdecnumber/decNumber.c:    printf(" ");
libdecnumber/decNumber.c:    printf(":");
libdecnumber/decCommon.c:       if ((num->lsd-ub)%3==0 && ub!=num->lsd) printf(" "); /* 4-space */
libdecnumber/decBasic.c:  printf("----- div=");
libdecnumber/decBasic.c:  printf("DivQuo:");
libdecnumber/decBasic.c:    printf("CoeffbL:");

These numbers look high enough, I would say any is "right". Looking at it, there are even more printf("literal") than fputs("literal", anything).

I don't agree with the sentinent that printf("foo: "); is ok. It is not fine, readable and understandable. Yes, people might know what it means, but IMHO it's bad practice from a semantic view. When I see printf I assume someone is printing something formatted, a value or something. In my opinion fputs is better, or for consistency printf("%s", "foo: "); or something like that.

It seems I worded my question a little incorrectly and everyone focused on the optimization part which I was not exactly asking about. I wanted to know if it is normal practice to use printf for non-formatted strings. But thanks anyway, got to know a little bit about all these optimizations too.

this should be the accepted answer, since it does address the OP doubts more

@pochopsp the question in that case of off-topic as it is opinion based

@pschulz I agree with you:  it is known that printf is named after "print formated"  and puts after "put string" . And we can be sure that some (extra) code will run in printf searching for (absent) %  specifiers in the format string.

In python print will be millions instructions more. Shell echo is used anytime, but it will be millions of instructions more. Premature optimization is evil here, unless you target a microcontroller and profiled your code. The argument is only correctness, with which i agree. Counter could be that nowadays we have compiler warnings and linters, to diagnose % without argument. I see no strong argunent to enforce one style, thus the recommendation.


As mentioned in the title, the string is not formatted and does not
end in a new line (so no puts). I am not sure about overheads and
optimizations, so what is the rule of thumb is this case?


printf is a much more complicated function than fputs. But usually, the processor time is not the main bottleneck when using I/O functions.

But if you use fprintf instead of printf most modern compilers will optimize your fprintf to fwrite. So use fprintf instead of printf if you want your code to be optimized in this case.
The question "what is better" is rather opinion-based. I prefer using printf for consistency. But there is no "gold rule" in this case.
void foo(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello World");
}

void zoo(void)
{
    fputs("Hello World", stdout);
}

void bar(void)
{
    printf("Hello World");
}

and the resulting code:
.LC0:
        .string "Hello World"
foo:
        mov     edx, 11
        mov     esi, 1
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR stdout[rip]
        jmp     fwrite
zoo:
        mov     edx, 11
        mov     esi, 1
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR stdout[rip]
        jmp     fwrite
bar:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     printf

https://godbolt.org/z/jKboo51br

It seems I worded my question a little incorrectly and everyone focused on the optimization part which I was not exactly asking about. I wanted to know if it is normal practice to use printf for non-formatted strings. But thanks anyway, got to know a little bit about all these optimizations too.

@GrandeKnight you worded it quite clearly - overhead and optimizations.

LMAO, what about the part earlier "I am not sure about". I have no idea about it and was not asking it from that point of view. So I did indeed word it incorrectly.


what is the rule of thumb is this case?

Better to favor fputs() to avoid strings with a "%" in it.  It might not today, but may in the future.
Otherwise, write code that is most clear - and that depends on the surrounding code.
